# Unraveling messy mesh

Tags: modeling, mesh

Isn't it possible to unravel entangled mesh in the blender 2.8?

My messy mesh is as follow:

[image: My messy mesh]

I don't know where it went wrong. Can anyone give some tips for handling an issue like this? I don't even expect some magic tools for unraveling this situation but just some tips or knowhows for a situation like this.

Comment: you can delete this part and use the Grid Fill tool (Ctrl F), but do you need so many faces?

Comment: I don't know do I need so many faces, because there can be a more efficient way to express an icing on the donut. I gotta try your advice with Grid Fill

Comment: having so many faces make things more complicated, you could first try a Ctrl E > Un-Subdivide to simplify it, then if you want to fake a smooth object, give it a Subdivision Surface modifier

Comment: Thanks for your advice :D the problem comes to much easier!